# Load image folder data set using name

Tags: python

---

I have a folder for image data set , and I wanna load this folder to be a training data set using python [this  image of my folder and it`s images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONgXJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one directory then you can use `os.listdir()` or if you want to lookup recursively then look up `os.walk()`.